# About powering USB device on Linux: Android camera app recognizes USB camera but Ubuntu doesn't

Tags: 10.04, usb, power-management, android, camera

On my notebook, I have a USB camera, 32-bit Ubuntu 10.04 running on SD Card and Android Jelly Bean on flash memory.

Ubuntu doesn't recognize the camera (even the USB port), cause it doesn't offer any power supply to it, for some reason. If I connect a wire between a powered USB port and the camera USB port, then dmesg recognizes my the USB port and camera.

However, if I remove my SD Card, my laptop boots Android JB. It also doesn't recognize the USB port where the camera is connected. But as I launch the camera application, somehow the USB gets power supply and starts working! There is some trick on Android's camera service that powers the USB Port.

Does anyone know anything about this?

This is the `lsusb` output when the USB camera port gets a power supply through the wire I connect.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:2ba0 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 1e4e:0102  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is the normal `lsusb` output, without the USB camera/port being recognized.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:2ba0 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This is `dmesg` when I connect the wire. Notice it disconnects cause it's not easy to stand still holding the wire.

```
$ dmesg | tail    
[  483.790202] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Camera (1e4e:0102)    
[  483.797666] input: USB2.0 Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input4    
[  484.608278] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 8    
[  486.123368] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
[  486.258975] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error -71    
[  486.320237] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1    
[  486.896696] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd    
[  487.040213] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Camera (1e4e:0102)    
[  487.047682] input: USB2.0 Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
/input/input5    
[  491.890035] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 11
```

If possible, where could I find the source code containing the operations executed by the camera app?

Comment: Add detail: *What is the output line, from **lsusb**, when the device is attached (and recognised) by Ubuntu?* Also, what version of Ubuntu? (eg. 12.04, 12.10, 32bit/64bit)

Comment: Include in your question the dmesg output related to USB, too.

Comment: Thanks for the interest! I don't have access to the machine right now, but will in a few hours. @david6: Ubuntu doesn't recognize it. As I said, I have to manually connect a wire to power the USB port. I will post the output of dmesg when I do that.

Comment: @Eric Carvalho: I will add it as soon as I go to work, tomorrow. Thanks for the interest!

Comment: @david6 There you go, and details about Ubuntu. Hope it helps.

Comment: @EricCarvalho There you go, dmesg output when I connect the wire manually. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This device (**1e4e:0102**) should show up as: Etron Technologies, 'USB 2.0 Camera'

see: [Linux UVC driver and tools](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/)

The site suggested that this should be fully supported, and yet it is not ..

---

You haven't yet identified hat version of **Ubuntu** you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll read your reference. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, I've included that already!

Comment: According to the list of supported devices, the 1e4e:0102 device is supported, isn't it?